# How to access GCP data on browser via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, browser, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to access and use this Google could platform data in the browser console using JavaScript:
[image]

However, I can't seem to get it work. I used to be able to access it like: `'${crs.404136.gaming_affinity}'`, but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Do you access other properties? For example profile?

Comment: I used to be able to access everything under 'profileAttributes' directly. For example '${crs.404136.gaming_affinity}'. I didn't have to reference profileAttributes or anything higher than that @Enver

Comment: Can you check console? Single quote or template literal (with backtick)?

Comment: @Enver I used to be able to access it with single quotes, no back ticks. Neither works at the moment. I can't access any part of the object via javascript in the console

Comment: How do you get data? Can you share code with us?

Comment: I get the data via GCP API, which I access via the networks tab in the browser. My question is to find out how I can use this data in the browser console via javascript. @Enver

Comment: You can see data in browser's network response. But if you want to access data in console you must add this data on browser's `window` object where you programmatically request and got. And access in console. Can you convert this discussion to chat?